# Telerik Silverlight RadChart Multiple Y-Axis

Tags: silverlight, telerik, radchart

I have a Telerik Silverlight RadChart where I am trying to use multiple Y-Axis's. I have tried the examples but they do not work for me. Does anyone have a working example of multiple Y-Axis with this control?

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This example works pretty well:
http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/MultipleYAxes

Also, this help topic explains the feature in detail: 
http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radchart-features-axes-multiple-y-axes.html

Comment: Vladimir, Thanks for the answer. You must be really good at Telerik. I got the demo to work in my code. However, I still have issues when trying to bind the Additional Y-Axis to my data. Can you please help me? Thanks!!!